# start restricted node.js app on boot

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, raspberry-pi

I'm having trouble running a node.js app when my raspberry pi boots up.

The script isn't anything special - just a hello world web server. But, it runs on port 80.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.end('Hello Apadfdche!\n');
}).listen(80, '192.168.0.1');
```

If I run this was only "node script.js" I get a permission error because everything on low port ranges requires special permission - run with "sudo" fixes that.

But, how do I automatically start my node app when my raspberry pi boots up?

I created a bash script in /etc/init.d

When I call my bash script manually from the command line using "sudo /etc/init.d/myscript" it starts the nodejs webserver without a problem. But when I let it execute normally via init.d on boot, it fails. In it I've tried invoking node in two ways

First :

```
/usr/local/bin/node /var/www/server.js
```

Second :

```
su -l "pi" -c "/usr/local/bin/node /var/www/server.js"
```

In both cases my node app throws the same exception as when I try to run it from the command line without "sudo", so I'm assuming it's still not getting the right permissions it needs to run. Trying to use "root" instead of "pi" doesn't help.

How can I run my script when my pi starts? For what it's worth, I don't *have* to use init.d, as long as it runs, I'm happy.

Comment: A better place for sysadmin stuff is probably serverfault.com or unix.stackexchange.com (not that this is off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that I know of.

You can set it up to start at startup via chkconfig, but I'm not too familiar with this method for self-made services

The other way is to set it up to start at startup within crontab:
1. run: sudo crontab -e
2. Your default editor should open and you will either see an empty file if there hasn't been any cron jobs set up for the root user or a few entries that look like "0 * * * * echo 'hello world'"
3. Write in "@reboot bash /etc/init.d/myscript" without the quotes into the file
4. Save and close and restart your server to see if it works.

This will essentially run the command at reboot/startup

Comment: Still getting permission errors I'm afraid, and I'm not even sure if its bash or nodejs. I managed to find a workaround eventually, but that meant giving up running node on port 80 directly, it just doesn't seem to want to work.